# Show that X is uniformly distributed

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

We have

$$
f(x, y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
{\frac{2 x^{2}}{y^{3}}} & {\text { if } 0<x<1, x<y} \\
{0} & {\text { if else }}
\end{array}\right.
$$

Show that is a valid PDF. **DONE**

Show Show that X is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$. **This is where I'm stuck. Also, I'm not sure where this big "x" suddenly comes from**.

Comment: Presumably this is the distribution of a pair $(X,Y)$, so you need to show that $P[X \in A] = m(A)$ for all Borel subsets of $(0,1)$.

Comment: What is m here?

Comment: Lebesgue measure, but @infinity's answer is probably what was intended.

Comment: Something does not look right to me.

Comment: @copper.hat what? can you take a look at my answer? i wrote all the details now.

Comment: I think you are missing a factor of ${3\over 2}$ and is should by $Y$?

Comment: Scratch that, I was thinking $y \le 1$.

Comment: @copper.hat i did too at first sight.. but then in the calculations i saw it isn't :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you showed that $\int_{\Bbb R^2} f_{X,Y}(x,y) dxdy =1$ and now you want to show that $X$ is uniform on $[0,1]$.

Do that by the following formula:

$f_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy$.

So,you need to show that $f_X(x)=1_{[0,1]}(x)$.

And you can do that as follows:

If $x\notin [0,1] $ then , $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=0$ for all $y$ so $f_X(x)=0$.

if $x\in [0,1]$ then $f_{X,Y}(x,y) \ne 0 $ only if $ y>x $ so $f_X(x)=\int_x^\infty 2x^2y^{-3}dy = 1$ , so indeed $f_X(x) = 1_{[0,1]}(x)$ and $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Okay. I'm not show what the last notion mean: $$
f_{X}(x)=1_{[0,1]}(x)
$$

Comment: $1_{[0,1]}(x) =1 $ if $x\in [0,1]$ and $0$ otherwise, this means that $X$ is uniform on $[0,1]$

Comment: Alright. What should the lower and upper bound be instead of infinity and minus infinity? 1 and 0, right.

Comment: it depends on $x$

Comment: if $x\notin [0,1]$ then for all $y $ , $f_{X,Y}(x,y) =0$ so $f_X(x) = 0 $

Comment: if $x\in [0,1]$ then the bounds are $y>x$ so $\int_{x}^\infty 2x^2y^{-3}dy$

Comment: I get the integral you asked me to calculate equal 1. How can I do a sanity check on this?

Comment: @Xenusi i got 1 also, so i guess the room for error got smaller :)

Comment: you just showed $f_X = 1_{[0,1]} $ , so this exactly means $X$ is uniform on $[0,1]$

Comment: Thanks I think I get it :-)!

Comment: You could post your answer as an answer so you can get a checkmark if you want.

Comment: it is an answer :P

Comment: Oh, did not see that.